# Solving $\frac{dx}{dt} = -\lambda \cdot x$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

In a book, the solution is said to be:

$$
x^0 \cdot e^{-\lambda(t-t^0)}
$$

I do following steps to obtain that formula (almost exactly it):

$$
\frac{dx}{dt} = -\lambda \cdot x \\
\frac{dx}{-\lambda x}=dt \\
\frac{1}{-\lambda}\int\frac{dx}{x}=\int dt \\
\frac{\ln x + B}{-\lambda} = t + A \\
\ln x + B = -\lambda(t+A) \\
\ln x = -B -\lambda(t+A) \\
x = e^{-B}\cdot e^{-\lambda(t+A)}
$$

So I almost have it, however, there is "+A" not "-A". Can I just adjust the sign to be more "reasonable"? This bothers me. I obtained "+A" not "-A", why should I then write $t-t_0$? "B" being negative in $e^{-B}$ can also be bothering. Can I just replace all that with $x^0$? Why?

Comment: $A$ is any arbitrary constant. It can be replaced by another constant $-A$. Meanwhile, does the problem specify any initial conditions?

Comment: Just $x(t^0) = x^0$

Comment: The point made by @GoodDeeds applies. Also, you can see that when $t=-A$ (which could be considered as $t_0$) you get $x=e^{-B}$ which can be considered as $x_0$. You can therefore replace $e^{-B}$ with $x_0$. Think of these as the initial conditions (i.e. at $t=t_0$ we have $x=x_0$).

Comment: This "misses" the solutions such that $x_0\leqslant0$. The reason is that $$\int\frac{dx}x=\log|x|+C,$$ not $\log x+C$.